# How to make VSCode detecting moduleNameMapper from Jest (ts-jest)

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

My issue is described there: [github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/94474](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/94474): VS Code IDE is showing     Cannot find module  (2307) for every file using moduleMappings

Example:

jest.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  roots: ['<rootDir>/test'],
  transform: {
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': 'ts-jest'
  },
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/src/$1',
    '^@@/(.*)$': '<rootDir>/test/$1'
  }
}
```

part of the test file:

```
import { DateTimeInput } from '@/generated/prisma-client'
import { startTestServer } from '@@/helpers/apolloInstance'
import prisma from '@@/helpers/prismaInstance'
import { createUser } from '@@/helpers/userHelper'
import { toPromise } from 'apollo-link'
import gql from 'graphql-tag'
```

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "dist",
    "lib": ["es6", "es7", "esnext", "dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"],
      "@@/*": ["test/*"]
    },
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "plugins": [{ "transform": "typescript-transform-paths" }]
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules"]
}
```

The code causes this error:
[error in vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FPvsm.png)

Solution suggested in linked issue is not helpful, because it causes dozens of test files to transpile, what is not what I want to achieve. Is there any way to force VSCode to actually read jest conifg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution (maybe more like workaround) is to create higher order tsconfig for both tests and src, then create another tsconfig extending the previous one and specyfic folders to compile

Comment: Would be better with an example -